# How to check if the Apps current activity belongs to a package?

Tags: android, ios, adb, appium

I am using Appium for Abdroid /IOS testing. (java) 
I want to be able to check if the current activity of an app belongs to a package. In the sense when an App switches from one mode to another (say I close the app or switch to another app or open the notifications scroll) I want to be able to detect it. How can I achieve this?

I want to check if my current activity belongs to a specific package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the current activity name, use `driver.currentActivity();` which is included in the AndroidDriver class.

There is no direct call for current package, but it can be found out by looking at the attributes of existing elements in the device screen by calling `driver.getPageSource();`